# Plotting (X,Y) bar graph in C#,SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, graph, mschart

I am trying to plot an X(weeks),Y(Fuel Amount) graph showing the total amount of fuel consumed per given interval say week(s) but for now the graph is only showing Fuel Amount(Y) against Day(X) [image: Like this]. How can I best plot it showing all the amount of fuel consumed per week.Here is the code plotting the current graph `

```
         private void Load_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


           try
         {

             string selectQuery = "Select * from  Fuel_Attendend";
             cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                this.chart1.Series["Date"].Points.AddXY(dr.GetString(3), dr.GetInt32(6));

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

            connection.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
    }
```

`.This is the SQL table[image: SQL Table].

Comment: Not sure what you are missing but one thing I see: You add the y-values as string, which is almost always a mistake, albeit a common one. And here, when they are dates is certainly is wrong. - Other than that:  Maybe you want to add a Series for the sums?

Comment: Or maybe you simply want to change the sql to something like `select date, sum(amount) group by date...`?

Comment: If you want to group the amounts by week, you have to ... drum roll... group by week.  Change your select to have a `Select sum(fuelamount), DATEDIFF(week, '2011-05-30', Date) AS WeekNumber from Fuel_Attended group by WeekNumber`

Comment: @TaW can you please explain more..Thanks

Comment: Which part do you mean?

Comment: On swapping the columns..I did that but I am getting the "Specified cast is not valid " error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the amounts per week, the easiest way is to change your sql to group by week.  Something like...

```
select sum(Fuel_Amount), DATEDIFF(week, '2018-01-01', Date) AS WeekNumber from Fuel_Attended group by DATEDIFF(week, '2018-01-01', Date)
```

And you'll have to change the columns that you use to be the first and second column when you add the points to series 1.

```
this.chart1.Series["Date"].Points.AddXY(dr.Int32(0), dr.GetInt32(1));
```

Or you can use

```
select sum(Fuel_Amount), DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '1950-01-01', Date), '1950-01-01') AS WeekNumber from Fuel_Attended group by DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '1950-01-01', Date), '1950-01-01')
```

This gets you the week expressed as the Sunday's date for the start of the week. rather than just a number.

Comment: @Agapwlesu Thanks i did that however I am now getting the "Specified cast is not valid." error hence failing to load the graph. I am using the 'date' data type for Date and 'int' for Fuel_Amount in the SQLSERVER.

Comment: Like this.. this.chart1.Series["Date"].Points.AddXY(dr.GetDateTime(0), dr.GetInt32(1));

Comment: In your original code you used GetString for a date time column.  That "worked" - even though it did not give you the desired data, it gave you the values from that date column.  The last select, in my answer, generates a datetime value, so probably using GetString will work, instead of GetDateTime.  I would try that, or better yet, step through your code and see exactly where it fails, and what it is the object that is getting cast to the wrong thing and what is it that is expected by the code giving the exception. Then adjust the code.

Comment: Okay let me try using GETSTRING and I will give you the feedback.